# PHP db session handling with custom session id

Tags: session, php-5.3, sessionid

I am using DB session handling for my application. 
The session id generated is based on cookie.
can i overwrite this value with my custom unique id?
i want to overwrite this value when user logins successfully.

Is it possible to implement in this way?

Comment: Sure. Just pass it back and forth via GET or POST, and use it for authentication.

Comment: @alexis: i do not want to use GET or POST

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom session id using session_id(); before session_start();.

Example:

```
<?php
session_id('123abc');
session_start();

echo '<br /> The ID of the current session is: '. session_id();
?>
```

Comment: can i  do at the end of script
<?php
session_id('123abc');
session_start();

echo '<br /> The ID of the current session is: '. session_id();

session_id('new_id');
?>